# Concept of Gravitational potential energy

Tags: newtonian-gravity, potential-energy, definition, conventions

Change in Potential energy corresponding to a conservative force is defined as $$\Delta U = U_f - U_i=-W_f$$ and gravitational potential energy is $$\Delta U = U_f-U_i = -W_g $$ Suppose a mass $m_1$ is kept at a fixed point $A$ and a second mass $m_2$ is displaced from point $B$ to point $C$ such that $AB = r_1$ and $AC = r_2$.
$\therefore$ , $$\Delta U = -W_g = \int{\frac{Gm_1m_2}{r^2}}dr$$ $$U(r_2)-U(r_1) = Gm_1m_2\left(\frac{1}{r_1}-\frac{1}{r_2}\right)$$ Now I am free to choose any reference point thus if I take potential energy at  $U(r_1) = 0$ and $r_2 = \infty$ Then I will get potential energy at infinity as $$U(\infty) = \frac{Gm_1m_2}{r_1}$$ which I think is wrong as a reference point at $r_1$ the potential energy at infinity should be infinite.
So where I am wrong, is my concept of gravitational potential energy wrong itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I think is wrong as a reference point at r1 the potential energy at infinity should be infinite.

The potential energy at infinity is only infinite if it takes an infinite amount of work to get to infinity. However, because the gravitational force decreases rapidly with distance, a projectile rapidly reaches a space where the force of gravity is not strong enough to reverse its velocity. Potential energy keeps increasing, but there is a maximum value that is approached asymptotically.

We have actually built space probes that have escaped Earth's gravity and the Sun's gravity. Voyager 1 and 2 have exited the Solar System and are never coming back. If they don't run into anything, they will reach arbitrarily far distances. The only thing stopping them from actually reaching infinity is the infinite time it would take to get there. To reach such a state, it only took the energy in the rocket fuel and some kinetic energy stolen from planets during planetary slingshots.

There are systems with a potential energy that reaches infinity at infinite distance. The spring potential energy $U = \frac{1}{2}kx^2$ is an example. When $x=\infty$, $U=\infty$ because the spring force keeps getting stronger as the spring is stretched.

Comment: This comment is probably so inane that I shouldn't even be making it, but, much as I gotta luv this answer, wouldn't the interstellar medium (an atom of this & an atom of that, here & there) sorta wear Voyager down till it would lose its shape, infinitely short of infinity?  (Or, are there no limits to my own density?)

Comment: Still, I gotta give it a point, since it drew a gasp from my worn-out throat, which only rarely (if ever) formulates a question as good as the OP's....

Comment: Also, maybe a Big Crunch would (sorta) put Humpty-Voyager together again....

Comment: Seriously, this answer gave me a glimpse of how Aguirre & Gratton's  "Steady-state eternal inflation" might work, & the question didn't even have a "cosmology" tag....

Comment: @Edouard In all physics problems, we have to decide how much detail we want to include. Is there friction? Air resistance? Other planets? The gravitational forces of the rest of the stars in the galaxy? If you want to travel to another planet from Earth, you'll use the escape velocity of Earth. If you're launching the voyager probes, you care about the escape velocity of the Sun. In my answer, I ignored everything in the universe except for a single body with gravity and a single projectile under its influence. This is normal for all problem solving: deciding what's relevant and what is not.

Comment: @Edouard As for Voyager, it's velocity with respect to the interstellar medium is so tiny that it is essentially hit on all sides equally by the medium, so it's velocity won't change. As for damage, there will be the occasional high-energy particle that penetrates it, possible damaging electronics or structures. Plus, the Voyager probes don't have a high enough velocity to escape our galaxy, so it is more accurate to say that the probes will eventually settle into their own orbits around the galactic center.

Comment: @Edouard Again, this is about choosing how much detail you want in an answer before the answer becomes meaninglessly detailed.

Answer (score 1):

If you let $r_1$ go to $0$ with nonzero $m_1$, you've defined a region with positive mass and zero volume, hence infinite density. That's a gravitational singularity. Whether such things exist or not is anyone's guess, but if they did, they would be the centers of black holes.

While Newtonian gravity won't accurately describe such a system, it is correct that for an object starting at a gravitational singularity, it would take infinite energy to lift the object to any radius $r>0$.

For a uniform density sphere of density $\rho$, radius $R>r$, the mass under a given radius from the center $m_1(r) = \frac {4\pi \rho}{3}r^3 $, and $U(r)$ simplifies to $\frac {4\pi \rho G m_2}{3}r^2$

---

You find similar apparent infinities with other forces. The specifics differ but in each case the answer is that the case in which $r \to 0$ is a situation in which your model doesn't describe anything real. This can be because there's nothing real to describe that has the modeled characteristics, because reality with such characteristics represents a case in which the model is inapplicable, or both.

Comment: I think you got the question wrong I didn't take $r_1 =0$ I took potential energy at $r_1$ $U(r_1) = 0$ now I have corrected the mistake.

Comment: I answered the question that you asked, which had $r_1=0$, so I think really it was you who got the question wrong... For the changed question, you just need to check your algebra. $U(\infty) = Gm_1m_2/\infty = 0$ for all $m_1, m_2$; and $U(r_1) = 0$ iff $m_1 = 0$ or $m_2 = 0$

Comment: That is, using the normal definition of potential energy, which has 0, not some finite nonzero value, at infinity. If you want to declare an arbitrary radius $r_1$ to have $U'(r_1)=0$, that's equivalent to transforming $U' = U - U(r_1)$, so in that case it's correct to have $U'(\infty) = U(\infty) -U(r_1) = -U(r_1)$ as you calculated.

Answer (score 0):

No the equation that you have derived isn't wrong. What actually is at fault here is the logic that potential energy at infinity must be infinite. This is completely incorrect. For example consider the following equation:
$$a-b = c$$

In this equation the only given information is the difference in magnitude of the two said quantities (a and b). Therefore if the value of b turns out to be 0 then $a=c$.

Since you have not provided any background as to why you think the potential must be infinite hence I cannot supply any intuitive answer for it.

---

Regarding the comment:

> I thought that the potential energy at infinity should be infinite because as we increase the distance from the fixed object the gravitational potential energy increases

Consider that you have fixed the value of $U(r)$ at $r=r_0$ to be $c$. As you correctly state that Gravitational potential energy increases as we go away from that point. Therefore $U(r) > U(r_0)$ if $r>r_0$. But what you failed to notice is that the rate at which the difference $U(r)-U(r_0)$ grows gets slower and slower as we go away from $r_0$ because $F_g$ (Force of gravitation) gets smaller and smaller. This when evaluated as limit gives a finite value and hence the value is not infinite at infinity.

Comment: I thought that the potential energy at infinity should be infinite because as we increase the distance from the fixed object the gravitational potential energy increases. Also I wasn't able to get your answer so could you please explain it more deeply.

Comment: The answer tries to explain that since the difference between the gravitational potential energy at two points is finite (given by the equation you derived). Therefore fixing the value of $U(r)$ at $r=0$ fixes its value at all other points including the limit when $r \to \infty$.

Comment: @AdityaSingh the answer has been updated.

Comment: Thank you to all for their answers. I have understood what gravitational potential energy means.

Answer (score 0):

Other answers are making this way too complicated.

The potential energy equation you quoted is only valid outside of a uniform sphere of mass. Inside a uniform sphere, the potential energy is actually constant. Therfore that constant should be set to the minimum of potential energy.

$U(r < R) = C$

$U(r=0) = U(r = R) = C$.

We make this C negative out of convenience so that it's 0 at $r = \infty$.

Comment: This is false. You may be thinking of a spherical shell. Consider the motion of a rock dropped down a mine shaft: obviously potential energy is being exchanged for kinetic energy as the rock's radius from the center of the earth decreases.

Comment: @gs oh right - it actually decreases inside (actually strengthens the original argument)